# If a finite group $G$ has a normal subgroup $N$ of order $p$ where $p$ is the smallest prime divisor of the group order, then $Z(G)$ is nontrivial

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ the smallest prime number with $p \mid |G|$. I want to show: if $G$ has a normal subgroup $N \trianglelefteq G$ of order $p$, then $G$ has a nontrivial center.

My idea was to maybe let $G$ operate on $N$ per conjugation, and then somehow use the [class equations](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Class_equation_of_a_group). But I had trouble so far on really getting started. If I define the group operation $\phi: G \times N \to N, (g, n) \mapsto g n g^{-1}$, I would somehow need to get some information about the orbits in order to apply the class equation. But I don't really know how I can concretely do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$N$ is normal, so it's a union of conjugacy classes of $G$. The whole group $N$ can't be a single conjugacy class because $e \in N.$ Since each conjugacy class has size dividing $|G|$, the only other possibility is that every element of $N$ is its own conjugacy class, so $N$ is contained in the center.